# mysql update trigger old, new row's column log

Tags: mysql, triggers

**my update trigger**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(100);
IF (OLD.authUId <> NEW.authUId) THEN SET s = CONCAT(s,'&authUId=', OLD.authUId); END IF;
IF (OLD.autPId <> NEW.autPId) THEN SET s = CONCAT(s,'&autPId=', OLD.autPId); END IF;
.....

INSERT INTO l_dblog(src,newId,oldValue) VALUE('auth_up',new.authId,s);
END
```

**inserted row oldValue column always null insert, whats my problem ?**

**I have delete trigger is succes work**

my Delete trigger:

```
 BEGIN
      DECLARE s VARCHAR(60);
      SET s = CONCAT('&authUId=', OLD.authUId,'&autPId=', OLD.autPId,'&authTypeId=', OLD.authTypeId,'&authValue=', OLD.authValue);   
    INSERT INTO l_dblog(src,newId,oldValue) 
     VALUE('auth_del',OLD.authId,s);
    END
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set default value of variable s as blank in your update query and then check weather trigger is working or not. If not than what error you got after running the trigger.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
IF (OLD.authUId <> NEW.authUId) THEN SET s = CONCAT(s,'&authUId=', OLD.authUId); END IF;
IF (OLD.autPId <> NEW.autPId) THEN SET s = CONCAT(s,'&autPId=', OLD.autPId); END IF;
.....

INSERT INTO l_dblog(src,newId,oldValue) VALUE('auth_up',new.authId,s);
END
```